# Laravel Seeding missing classes

Tags: php, laravel

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial) until I need to generate seeds using: `php artisan db:seed`. It always said that my `Article` and `User` class are not found.

I have looking for solution like in:

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/unable-to-run-php-artisan-dbseed-due-to-missing-class (setting up composer.json's auto load paths and `composer dump-autoload`)
- [Laravel cannot find class of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290088/laravel-cannot-find-class-of-a-package)
- I have deleting my vendor folder and do `composer install` again
- Also importing the file manually, `require_once` with relative path to the model from the seeding or root of the projet, but neither works.

I think this should work out-of-the-box but it isn't. What is my problem? And what is my solution?

EDIT 1: Someone requested seeders codes here you are!

Article Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Let's truncate our existing records to start from scratch.
        Article::truncate();

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        // And now, let us create a few articles in our database:
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i ++) {
            Article::create([
                'title' => $faker->sentence,
                'body' => $faker->paragraph,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

User Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Let's clear the user table first
        User::truncate();

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        // Let's make sure everyone has the same password and
        // let's hash it before the loop, or else our seeder
        // will be too slow.
        $password = Hash::make('toptal');

        User::create([
            'name' => 'Administrator',
            'email' => 'admin@test.com',
            'password' => $password,
        ]);

        // And now let's generate a few dozen users for our app:
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
            User:;create([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => $password,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Database Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code. :D

Comment: Nice! Which ones? Codes are scafolded from Laravel.

Comment: the seeder, please :)

Comment: There should be no problem, since the codes are generated. Nonetheless, you got it fam.

Comment: you should use the `Model`s fully qualified name if you're not *importing* it. try `App\User` instead of `User` only. or just try importing it at the top of the file: `use App\User;`

Comment: are you sure? what is the namespace of your `User` model?

Comment: Nevermind it is working, I forgot there are two things that need `App\`. But, why there is nothing as such in the tutorial I read though?

Thanks mate!

Comment: i dont know lol. you're welcome :)

Comment: You can add answer if you want...

Comment: done. thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either import the models that you've use so you can use just the *Model*'s class name in your code or use the fully qualified name of the *Model*.

E.g., instead of just `User`, use `App\User`.

Use imports if you think you will have many instance where you will use the `User` class name, to avoid the hassle of typing the fully qualified name.

```
<?php
...
use App\User;
...
$users = User::all(); // <-- now you can do this.
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should import the full class path, i.e.- `App\User`. Then regenerate the autoload file with- `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial. Just add a line "use App\Article;" so that your class will find the appropriate class.
Its like including a header file path in c/c++.

Comment: Why do you suggest `App\Article` when the both two year old answers both suggest `App\User`? In which file are you suggesting this needs to be added?