# Laravel 10 seeder cannot find class, php artisan complains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have exactly the same issue as [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255953/laravel-seeding-missing-classes), but none of the solutions provided works for me.

I too have been trying to follow exactly the same [Laravel API tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial), and got stumbled by the Laravel Seeder failure.

This is my model app\Models\Article.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

This is my seeder database\seeders\ArticlesTableSeeder

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use app\Models\Article;


class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder {
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   */
  public function run(): void {

    Article::truncate();
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

    // And now, let's create a few articles in our database:
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
      Article::create([
          'title' => $faker->sentence,
          'body' => $faker->paragraph,
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run "$ php artisan db:seed --class=ArticlesTableSeeder" it complains about 'Class "app\Models\Article" not found'

I have cleared the cache and ran "$ composer dump-autoload" a few times but that didn't help.

Comment: It should be `use **App**\Models\Article`. If you use an IDE, you can import the class and then you don't have to type it manually (or copy/paste)

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code for seeder

```
    <?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Faker\Factory;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use DB;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            DB::table('articles')->insert([
                [
                    'title' => $faker->sentence,
                    'body' => $faker->paragraph
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Factotories in this case.

database/factories/**ArticleFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ArticleFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => fake()->words(2, true),
            'body' => fake()->words(5, true),
        ];
    }
}
```

database/seeders/**ArticleSeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        //this will create 50 records in DB, no need to use for loop
        Article::factory(50)->create();
    }
}
```

**Then execute:**

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ArticleSeeder
```